# Typo3 Fluid: elseif inline notation

Tags: fluid, typo3-8.x, viewhelper

Is there an inline notation for the following example?

```
<f:if condition="{value}==1">
    <f:then>Value is 1</f:then>
    <f:else if="{value}==2">Value is 2</f:else>
</f:if>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

probably it will be the cascading of `if`-viewhelpers:

```
{f:if(condition:'{value}==1', 
    then:'Value is 1', 
    else:'{f:if(condition:\'{value}=2\', then:\'Value is 2\')}'
)}
```

with the usual drawback of escaping string-delimiter for stacked inline viewhelpers.

Comment: Yes, I know this! I thought there would perhaps be a "flat" solution

Answer (score 1):

*your condition will default to 'Value is 2' although the value might not be ...* this is not true, anyhow a bit more complete:

```
<f:if condition="{value}==1">
  <f:then>Value is 1</f:then>
  <f:else if="{value}==2">Value is 2</f:else>
  <f:else>Value is not valid</f:else>
</f:if>
```

simple inline annotation that does not output anything if the two conditions are not met:

```
{f:if(condition:'{value}==1',
  then: 'Value is 1',
  else: '{f:if(condition:\'{value}==2\',then: \'Value is 2\')}'
)}
```

add the else clause in the second condition:

```
{f:if(condition:'{value}==1',
  then: 'Value is 1',
  else: '{f:if(condition:\'{value}==2\',
    then: \'Value is 2\',
    else: \'Value is not valid\'
  )}'
)}
```

Comment: `your condition will default to 'Value is 2' although the value might not be` -  I cannot see that. My example just shows nothing if the value is neither 1 or 2 (like expected)

Comment: Ok, TYPO3 often is surprising to me, on my localhost I had this result but I intended to give some extra info, what about the inline anotation ? that did work on my localhost... I will correct my answer...

Comment: Yes, the inline notation works like this! I hoped there is a way without nesting.